# In controller, how to get object initialized in directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

this is my first time to use AngularJS and GoogleMap.
In my program, I want to set a marker at current location on my GoogleMap, the code below is how I use directive to initialize the map (basically comes from the Internet)

```
app.directive("appMap", function () {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        replace: true,
        template: "<div></div>",
        scope: {
            center: "=",        // Center point on the map (e.g. <code>{ latitude: 10, longitude: 10 }</code>).
            markers: "=",       // Array of map markers (e.g. <code>[{ lat: 10, lon: 10, name: "hello" }]</code>).
            width: "@",         // Map width in pixels.
            height: "@",        // Map height in pixels.
            zoom: "=",          // Zoom level (one is totally zoomed out, 25 is very much zoomed in).
            mapTypeId: "@",     // Type of tile to show on the map (roadmap, satellite, hybrid, terrain).
            panControl: "@",    // Whether to show a pan control on the map.
            zoomControl: "@",   // Whether to show a zoom control on the map.
            scaleControl: "@"   // Whether to show scale control on the map.
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            var toResize, toCenter;
            var map;
            var currentMarkers;
            // update the control
            function updateControl() {

                // update size
                if (scope.width) element.width(scope.width);
                if (scope.height) element.height(scope.height);

                // get map options
                var options =
                {
                    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-42, 171),
                    zoom: 6,
                    mapTypeId: "roadmap"
                };
                if (scope.center) options.center = getLocation(scope.center);
                if (scope.zoom) options.zoom = scope.zoom * 1;
                if (scope.mapTypeId) options.mapTypeId = scope.mapTypeId;
                if (scope.panControl) options.panControl = scope.panControl;
                if (scope.zoomControl) options.zoomControl = scope.zoomControl;
                if (scope.scaleControl) options.scaleControl = scope.scaleControl;

                // create the map
                map = new google.maps.Map(element[0], options);
```

below content is my controller

```
app.controller("appCtrl", function ($scope) {

    // current location
    $scope.loc = { lat: -42, lon: 171 };
    $scope.zoom = 6;   
    $scope.gotoCurrentLocation = function () {
        var c = $scope.getCurrentLoc();
        alert(c.latitude + "    " + c.longitude);
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
                var c = position.coords;
                $scope.gotoLocation(c.latitude, c.longitude);
           });
            return true;
       }
        return false
    };

    $scope.gotoLocation = function (lat, lon) {
        if ($scope.lat != lat || $scope.lon != lon) {
            $scope.loc = { lat: lat, lon: lon };
            //$scope.zoom = 14;
            //if (!$scope.$$phase) $scope.$apply("loc", "zoom");
            if (!$scope.$$phase) $scope.$apply("loc");
        }
    };
```

For now, I got a bottom which triggers the gotoCurrentLocation(), what I want to do is add a marker at the current location. Therefore, in controller, I think I need to get the map object which is initialized in the directive, then add mark to it. Is there a way to do that, actually I am not sure whether this is a right way though.

I have thought some other ways. For example, put the getCurrentPosition in a separate function and pass the function into directive, and set marker there.

Please offer some help friends, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a property on you directive like `onInit` and pass there a function from your controller that would receive a map object when it is initialized.

```
app.directive("appMap", function () {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        replace: true,
        template: "<div></div>",
        scope: {
            center: "=",        // Center point on the map (e.g. <code>{ latitude: 10, longitude: 10 }</code>).
            markers: "=",       // Array of map markers (e.g. <code>[{ lat: 10, lon: 10, name: "hello" }]</code>).
            width: "@",         // Map width in pixels.
            height: "@",        // Map height in pixels.
            zoom: "=",          // Zoom level (one is totally zoomed out, 25 is very much zoomed in).
            mapTypeId: "@",     // Type of tile to show on the map (roadmap, satellite, hybrid, terrain).
            panControl: "@",    // Whether to show a pan control on the map.
            zoomControl: "@",   // Whether to show a zoom control on the map.
            scaleControl: "@",  // Whether to show scale control on the map.
            onInit: '&'         //This function would run when your map is initialized
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            var toResize, toCenter;
            var map;
            var currentMarkers;
            // update the control
            function updateControl() {

                // update size
                if (scope.width) element.width(scope.width);
                if (scope.height) element.height(scope.height);

                // get map options
                var options =
                {
                    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-42, 171),
                    zoom: 6,
                    mapTypeId: "roadmap"
                };
                if (scope.center) options.center = getLocation(scope.center);
                if (scope.zoom) options.zoom = scope.zoom * 1;
                if (scope.mapTypeId) options.mapTypeId = scope.mapTypeId;
                if (scope.panControl) options.panControl = scope.panControl;
                if (scope.zoomControl) options.zoomControl = scope.zoomControl;
                if (scope.scaleControl) options.scaleControl = scope.scaleControl;

                // create the map
                map = new google.maps.Map(element[0], options);
                scope.onInit(map);
```

Comment: Hi, your reply truly helped me solve the problem, thank you very much!